# How can I make TextView auto-size in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, autoresize

I would like to implement the method that auto-resize the text for better compatibility.

I followed this article:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview

and I write this code:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
        android:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
        android:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
        android:autoSizeTextType="none"
        android:fontFamily="@font/arimo"
        android:text="Ti piace Youtube?"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="#F8F3F3"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:autoSizePresetSizes="@array/autosize_text_sizes" />
```

What I'm wrong? the text doesn't auto-size and, for example, in Nexus S Emulator, I can't see the text full but it is cut.

thank
Elvis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use ssp and sdp. The ssp a scalable size unit for texts is android SDK that provides a new size unit - ssp (scalable sp). This size unit scales with the screen size based on the sp size unit (for texts). It can help Android developers with supporting multiple screens.and sdp This is the sibling of the sdp size unit that should be used for non text views. https://github.com/intuit/ssp and https://github.com/intuit/sdp use gradle and compile libraries like below

```
implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.4'
    implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.4'
```

in your layout activity xml for example for text you can provide like this

android:textSize="@dimen/_16ssp"
for layouts

android:layout_height="@dimen/_16sdp"
this will take care for any screens enjoy.

for text only add  `implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.4'` on gradle file then
here is the example on your xml file in TextView implement it like below

```
<TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Intuit"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_40ssp"/>
```

Comment: ok, can you explain to me how to use the SSP in android studio? sorry but i'm newbie in android studio

Comment: ok, the implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.4'
    implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.4',  where should they be inserted?

Comment: Elvis in your buil.gradel file  here is the documentation https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView` instead of `TextView` to have compatibility on older devices.

I guess the problem is in `android:autoSizeTextType="none"`, it should not be `none`. Also, in a simple way, there is no need to define `app:autoSizePresetSizes`, let the text view to calculate the proper size itself.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/arimo"
    android:text="Ti piace Youtube?"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="#F8F3F3"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    app:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
    app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
    app:autoSizeStepGranularity="1sp" />
```

Comment: i tried this but i continue to see the text cutted. I would like to add that the textview is located within a radiogroup.

Comment: Is it possible to share a screenshot? Do you want the text to be a single line?

Comment: yes, i have a long text: 6 words, not the sentence I reported. what do you want the screenshot of? radio group here: <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="376dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

Comment: Add `android:lines="1"` to the TextView attributes. I wanted to see the cutting text.

Comment: ok, here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jm7tCM9wqCtPSIhcBZb0K2kY_uoPAIBJ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The text in the screenshot and `Ti piace Youtube?` aren't matched. Are you sure you are working on correct textview?

Comment: You may want to change the `layout_height`.

See quote from Android docs: "Note: If you set autosizing in an XML file, it is not recommended to use the value "wrap_content" for the layout_width or layout_height attributes of a TextView. It may produce unexpected results." - https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/text-and-emoji/autosizing-textview

Answer (score -1):

you can use this : `android:autoSizeMaxTextSize=""`  but this needs api 26 , if its not the case you can replace `android` with `app`

with less than API 26, you can use the following which worked for me :

```
app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
    app:autoSizeMinTextSize="2sp"
    app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
```

replace the values with the ones that you want

Comment: don't work, sorry. I'm afraid about this. Thank you for your idea